how to back current data in summernote after cancel or close modal in ajax
how to back current data  in summernote after cancel or close modal in ajax ?
#editNewsModal = My Modal Name, for edit form
name="description" = Name field
$('body').on('click', '#button_close_edit', function(e) {
$('#editNewsModal').find('[name="description"]').prev().html('<span>Description</span>')
});

when I add or delete a word and it is not submitted, then the data will be the same as what I did, it does not return to the previous data as in the database.
